# Doing a join in a couple of sqlite tables is not working

Tags: sql, sqlite, join, inner-join

So I have this SQLite string

```
SELECT
a.anchor as [From Anchor],
c.anchor as [To Anchor]
FROM table1 a
JOIN table2 b ON b.toAnchor = a.anchor
JOIN table3 c ON c.anchor = b.fromAnchor
```

And there is no error when I execute it but it returns an empty table. There is data in all 3 of the tables and the data does match where it is supposed to but I get nothing.

Table1

```
filename | farea | anchor
_________________________
file.doc   N/A     srs100
```

Table2

```
type | filename | fromAnchor | toAnchor
_______________________________________
SRS      N/A       srs100      crs888
```

Table3

```
filename | farea | anchor
_________________________
file.doc   N/A     crs888
```

I know I could just use table 2 but I need it to be done this way to find areas where the from and to don't match.

If I cant find a way of doing it like this then I would like to find out a way that I can combine 2 tables so it would like this.

table1

```
type | filename | fromAnchor | toAnchor
_______________________________________
SRS      N/A       crs100      srs888
```

table2

```
type | filename | fromAnchor | toAnchor
_______________________________________
CRS      N/A       srs888      srd999
```

result

```
crs    | srs    | srd
_______________________________________
crs888  srs888   srd999
```

I can provide more info if needed. For now I would like to know if the sql call is correct.

Comment: SQL Looks correct. Double check your data. You are missing something there Try changing your joins to left joins and see which tables return nulls for its columns and you will know where the mismatched data is.

Comment: Well if I flip the join statements around the table is filled out but it repeats the CRS section over and over for every one SRS.

Comment: table 1 anchor and table2 to anchor have different values

Comment: Like so:

`crs100 srs101
crs100 srs102
crs100 srs103
crs100 srs104
crs102 srs101
crs102 srs102
crs102 srs103
crs102 srs104`

Comment: I doubt you can start from table1. for table1 as you are using same column with alias for joining condition to the other two tables wont find a match

Comment: So how do you think I should word it?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
a.anchor as [From Anchor],
c.anchor as [To Anchor]
FROM table1 a
JOIN table2 b ON b.fromAnchor = a.anchor
JOIN table3 c ON c.anchor = b.toAnchor
```

Comment: There is still no error in the string for the sql but it still wants to return no data.

Comment: worked in the sql fiddle but it doesn't work in my database. What do you think could be causing this? I made the fiddle based off of my database...

Comment: MAke sure the values in the joining columns are EXACTLY the same.Do a trim to elimnate empty spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT 
fromAnchor, 
toAnchor 
from table2 a
join table1 b on  a.fromAnchor =b.anchor
join table3 c on a.toAnchor =c.anchor
```

Comment: This worked in the sql fiddle but it doesn't work in my data base. What do you think could be causing this?

Comment: check the joining condition

Answer (score -1):

Turns out that the data in the database had been configured incorrectly. This turned out to work.

```
SELECT
TABLE1.toAnchor AS CRS,
TABLE1.fromAnchor AS SRS
FROM tbl_traces_srstraces
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE2.anchor = TABLE1.toAnchor
LEFT JOIN TABLE3 ON TABLE3.anchor = TABLE1.fromAnchor
```